# salesforce einstein CHATBOT and custom notification

Tags: einstein, chat, notification, bot

```
Messaging.CustomNotification notification = new Messaging.CustomNotification();
notification.setTitle('A CASE HAS BEEN ESCALATED!');
notification.setBody('Case # : ' +caseNumber+ ' subject : ' + caseSubject);
notification.setSenderId(Userinfo.getUserId());

CustomNotificationType type = [SELECT Id FROM CustomNotificationType WHERE DeveloperName = 'Confirmation_Message'];

notification.setNotificationTypeId(type.id);
notification.setTargetId(ownerId); // target object id
notification.send(new Set<String> { Userinfo.getUserId() });
```

When executing the aforementioned code on the anonymous window, a notification is successfully generated. However, when executing the Apex code within the Einstein chatbot, it fails to trigger despite having granted the class the necessary permissions. I have thoroughly investigated the issue but have not been able to identify the root cause. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is resolved by running the bot on Custom Chatbot User (Recommended)

By using a custom chat bot user account, you can ensure that your chat bot has the appropriate level of access and permissions to perform the tasks it needs to do. This can include functions such as retrieving data from Salesforce, updating records, or sending notifications to users.

In addition, using a custom chat bot user account can help improve the security and manageability of your chat bot, since you can control the specific actions it can perform and track its usage through the Salesforce audit trail.

Overall, using a custom chat bot user account is a best practice recommended by Salesforce, and can help ensure the proper functioning and security of your Einstein chat bot.